# Python ignoring sourced .env file

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I'm confused about the significance of `source .env` and why Python is not accessing those variables although those variables are accessible from bash.

When I manual `export FOO=foo`, Python sees the env, but not when I `source .env`

```
$ cat .env 
ENV=development
$ echo $ENV

$ echo $FOO

$ source .env 
$ export FOO=foo
$ echo $ENV
development
$ echo $FOO
foo
$ python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:27)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv("ENV"))
None
>>> print(os.getenv("FOO"))
foo
```

Comment: `ENV` is not exported, so.. ? Why would you expect python to see it?

Comment: I guess I though if bash was able to see $ENV that meant is was exported. What does "exported" mean to you? I suppose I don't understand that part.

Comment: `What does "exported" mean to you?` It means that a variable has set the export attribute. And you set that with `export` call. Nowhere you do `export ENV`..

Comment: So how would I easily go about exporting all key-value vars in an `.env` file? Thanks btw

Comment: Easily? `set -a`

Comment: Ah, i just say `export ENV=development` and then source that. sorry thanks

Comment: You can also simply write `export ENV` before or after you call `source`, as long as it is before you run Python. `export` itself doesn't modify the value of a variable; is simply sets the export attribute on a *name*. The only time the attribute is used is when you start a child process, at which time the current value of the variable is copied to the child. The value when you actually set the attribute isn't relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused about the significance of source .env

`source` just works like "include" in other languages, like in C it includes the content of other file. `source` just parses the text from other file as-if it would be typed in.

> Why Python is not accessing those variables although those variables are accessible from bash.

Because the variable is not exported, when the execution environment for python process is created, the value of that variable is not included in that environment.

> So how would I easily go about exporting all key-value vars in an .env file?

- Add `export` to each variable in `.env` file, or
- Use `set -a` to export all variables and then source the file, or
- Parse the `.env` file to extract variable names and set the export attribute on each variable with `export`.

Answer (score 1):

As KamilCuk said, `source` does not necessary "export". Variables must be **exported**, not just sources, so in my case I would just have `export ENV=development` in the `.env` file and source that.

Notice in this case `.env` is different on line 2.

```
$ cat .env 
export ENV=development
$ echo $ENV

$ echo $FOO

$ source .env 
$ export FOO=foo
$ echo $ENV
development
$ echo $FOO
foo
$ python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 15:43:27) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv("ENV"))
development
>>> print(os.getenv("FOO"))
foo
```

And to add to this, when I did `export FOO=foo`, this **both assigns and exports**, but in fact if you were to just do the following, you would create a bash var *without* export.

```
$ FOO=foo
$ echo $FOO
foo
```

In this case it's *assigned*, but not **exported**. Python needs it to be **exported**.